# Draggable resizing on it's own within a resizable draggable

Tags: jquery, draggable, droppable, resizable

When I drop a resizable draggable item into a resizable container with overflow: hidden, and then drag it around, it works as expected (being hidden where it overlaps with the edges of the container) EXCEPT on the right hand side.  If I drag it that way it starts resizing itself.

Sample application is here.  Just drag one of the characters into the first or second box, release, and try dragging it in different directions around the edges of the box.

http://www.thelionscall.com/wp-content/comic-creator/index-test-resize-bug.html

It may have to do with the 100% height and width on the img within the resizable draggable container, but that doesn't explain why it only happens on one side.

How can I get the right edge to behave like the other three?  Thanks.